# How do I perform a raster overlay analysis in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, c#, arcgis-engine

Using the "IMultivariateOp.MLClassify" Method, it will create a field call "Count",which can be used for calculating area, as shown in the figure below:

[image: MLClassify]

But now I want to calculate the increase area of two rasters, for example a raster in "2000" year and "2013" year.

So I have to analyze the overlay, as shown in the figure below:
[image: The algorithm or the increasement]

How do I execute this analysis in ArcObjects using C#?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I have made significant edits to the title and body of your post to clarify your question. If you feel that the essence of your question was not properly captured with these edits, feel free to edit your question as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach:

- Run the *IMultivariateOp.MLClassify* on year 2000 and year 2013 to create your 2 classification rasters, from your example they would have 9 classes.
- Multiply your classified year 2000 raster by 10
- Add your new, year 2000, raster to the 2013 classification raster. This gives the change between pixels so for example a final pixel of "72" would indicate it was originally 7 in 2000 and now 2 in 2013.

To be looking at change in the area specific to the overlay you would set the mask property in the [IRasterAnalysisEnvironment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRasterAnalysisEnvironment_Interface/00240000004r000000/) Interface. Make sure you set that before you add the rasters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and it seems that you got the issue I launched,would you give some explanation about the "multiply by 10"? I mean that,even if we do this,it seems useless,or I haven't clearly describe my issue when posted?

Comment: You are shifting the digit to the "left" so when you add the 2 rasters it's the coded combination that tells you exactly what has changed from what to what. If you did not then if you added the 2 classification rasters with your 9 classes then a final value for example of 8 does not say what changed from what, was it 3 to 5, 5 to 3, 4 to 4,7 to 1, 1 to 7....?

Comment: This approach works as you have less than 10 classes.

Comment: Yeah,thanks ,and this maybe a good ideal,but would you tell me that I must use the IRasterCursor to iterate the IPixelBlock? I have one more problem and I just can not work with this!!!!Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to use the IRasterCursor you have not explained why you are even thinking about it? This sounds like you are mixing something else with this thread? May be you need to post another separate question?

Comment: Thanks you...It seem there are lots of jobs to do with the detail.